# How to iterate over documents in MongoDB

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

The format of the database is as follows:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63868fe133e02dfcad69ef51"
  },
  "Timestamp": "2020-11-04 03:58:36",
  "state": "PA",
  "locality": "Cambria",
  "precinct": "Adams Township - Dunlo Voting Precinct",
  "geo": "42021-ADAMS TWP DUNLO",
  "totalvotes": 334,
  "Biden": 73,
  "Trump": 259,
  "filestamp": "NOVEMBER_04_2020_035836.json"
}
```

It is data from the election, where each document corresponds to a different timestamp for each precinct. Precinct is repeated at different timestamps, where the votes for Biden, Trump, and TotalVotes are updated. Therefore, the precinct timestamp combo is unique.

Let totalIncrement be the change in votes for all precincts between two Timestamps. Every precinct has a record at any certain timestamp that exists. I am trying to find the timestamp that has the largest increase in totalvotes, and what that increase is.

I tried sorting by timestamp and iterating over the number of votes at each timestamp, but the problem I have is the database is 486k documents, so I an unable to sort as I have the free version of Atlas and cannot use allowDiskUse.

Comment: Is `"totalvotes"` just for the `"precinct"`, or for all precincts?

Comment: @rickhg12hs "totalvotes" refers to the totalvotes for the precinct in the document at that timestamp. totalvotes at any document is equal to "Biden" + "Trump". If no new votes are recorded between two documents with the same precinct, but at a later timestamp, the totalvotes are the same

Comment: @rickhg12hs the database is very redundant, but thats just how it is

Comment: So, your description of `"totalIncrement"` is per `"precinct"`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs no, total Increment is the change in the total number of votes for all the precincts, between two timestamps

Comment: So, `"totalIncrement"` might the the change from one precinct to a different precinct?  This is difficult to comprehend without a dataset to look at and play with.